# writing a loop to find out the unique year based on value of two or more columnns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there a way to write loop to locate unique value based on two columns? i have tried following:

```
name    major   graduation year
x         y      2008
x         z      2009
```

What i have done is i have created the dataframe and try to do following afterwards:

```
BA = 
BAST = 
SD = C1[(C1.iloc[:,0]==BA) &(C1.iloc[:,1]==BAST]

unique_date = []
unique = SD['graduation year'].unique()
unique_date.append(sorted(unique))
print(unique_date)
```

so far it is working great however i have to put value of bA and BAST manually.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and hand worked desired outputs? It's difficult to know what you are asking. It sounds like you can just do a `.groupby(["name", "major"]).unique()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
C1.groupby(['name', 'major'])['graduation year'].unique()
```

You can try the following (not tested because of lack of sample data)

```
C1.groupby(['name', 'major'])['graduation year'].apply(lambda x:[x.min(), x.max()])
```

Comment: you hit the mark but im trying to get the date range afterwards. currently im getting bunch of [2004,2005.......

Comment: yes, because a group has multiple unique values, we need to aggregate them, what do you want to with them ?

Comment: i just need the range.

Comment: is there a way to make datafarme out of it?/

Comment: yes it worked however. i ran into a issue. there are the cases where years are like 2003, 2004, 2006, 2010. in this case iam looking for dates 2003-2004, 2006, 2010.

Comment: how is it a range then ?

Comment: yes it is not the range. I noticed it later there are few instances where there are gaps.